# Find limit of function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need find limit without L'Hospital rule.
$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{sinx}\right)$
I dont know how transform expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^x -1}{x}=1.$

2)$\lim_{  x  \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} =1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why do you specify $x\ne0$ ??

Comment: Yves. The function is not defined for x =0. Correct me if wrong,Peter.

Comment: Of course. But, look closely: you never use $f(0)$, do you ? Actually, it is very misleading to add $x\ne0$ because limits precisely *avoid* evaluating the function at the accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

With Taylor
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{\sin x}\right) = \lim _{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}{x}=\lim _{x\to 0} \dfrac{\frac{x}{1+x}}{x}=\lim _{x\to 0} \dfrac{1}{1+x}=1$$

or

$\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{\sin x} = \dfrac{\dfrac{e^{-x} -1}{-x}}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 1$

Comment: Why such an indirect approach ? By Taylor, $1-e^{-x}\approx x$.

Comment: you are right.....